# How do i make my site more accessible to blind people?

Tags: html, accessibility, user-agent, wai-aria, color-blindness

How do I make my site more accessible to blind people so that they can use voice-over options on mouse hover/brill screens/

Do I need to make certain data clearer? e.g large titles/meta data etc.?

Can I identify if a blind user entered the site using user-agent and display different more friendly content? Do they use some kind of a different version of browser that I can identify?

Comment: I was checking out some 508 compliance things myself and stumbled upon this link http://blog.adrianroselli.com/2014/06/accessible-bootstrap-frameworks.html which details two frameworks that you might be able to use. I am a big fan of bootstrap so the Assets framework looked promising to me

Answer (score 0):

The rules to make applications accessible are described in WAI-ARIA: Accessible Rich Internet Applications.

There are a set of rules and markup to allow the screen readers or browsers to behave better with them.

Here is the recomendation http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/

For sure, there are more sites that cover this recomendations in a easier way. And component libraries that would make the work already done.